# Windows Server 2003 - applied WCRY patch - restarted then RDP Failed (the workstation driver is not installed)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, rdp, windows-patching

Installed the WCRY patch found here http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4012598

After restarting, the server started having issues with the network interface.

RDP does not work, error: The workstation driver is not installed.
Also, the client computers cannot connect to the server's network drives.

Comment: Did you know that Windows Server 2003 extended support ended on July 14, 2015? Microsoft hasn't provided any security updates for it in almost two years now! It might actually be more safe now that it doesn't have network connectivity.

Comment: @EsaJokinen; That is not correct. Microsoft issued a patch for XP and Server 2003 for this specific vulnerability even though those products are EOL. Given the severity of the hack and the fact that it has existed for years, it's a very good thing that they did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had to uninstall and re-install the Client for Microsoft Networks to solve the issue.

Found the solution here: https://www.pntbrother.com/fix-the-workstation-driver-is-not-installed-windows-server-2003-active-directory/

"Go to “Control Panel“, and click “Network Connections“. Right-click your current network adapter, and click “Properties“. (Could be a wireless or a wired interface) Find and uninstall “Client for Microsoft Networks“. After uninstalling the item, click “Install” and choose “Client for Microsoft Networks” to install again (When you install Client for Microsoft Networks, it is located under Client category). If Windows asks you to restart, restart your Windows Server 2003."