# windows server 2003 target backup, backupexec 10d parent server: target remains almost out of space

Tags: windows-server-2003, backupexec

The company I work for continues to rely on backupexec 10d and windows 2003 target servers backup (system state and active partition).

All of a sudden and following successful completion of job, when the scheduled job fires from the parent backupexec 10d and in a few minutes the target server almost remains with about 1.5 GB available space, eating up to 15 GB in only a few minutes...prior to execution the target has approx. 17 GB of free space...

Shadow copies seem disabled on the target volume...
Upper limit was set at 8GB, approx. 10% of total volume space...
Vss service on, auto on target...backupexec on, auto on target...

Has anyone else dealt with such an issue?

Comment: Not with Windows Server 2003 in 2017, because we don't use [EOL operating systems](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-2003).

Comment: [Windows Server 2003 end of life is July 14, 2015. Get help with planning your Windows Server 2003 migration](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-2003).  And buy a new hard drive while you're at it, FFS.  **MY PHONE** has more free space than your backup target server.

Comment: Budget issues...no money to perform upscaling, upgrading whatsoever...the problem at hand is that while the job succeded previously, now it fails...

Comment: Apparently the data isn't valuable, then? What's the industry? A barbershop?

Comment: Be my guest and persuade the upper management for the obvious...being that this is a technical forum, any technical suggestions based on your experience?

Comment: As far as the above mentioned EOL facts all of us know and struggle to persuade the ones that need to be persuaded...yet...the fact remains...threads exist here that pertain to windows 2003 (https://serverfault.com/questions/850288/windows-server-2003-applied-wcry-patch-restarted-then-rdp-failed-the-workst)...and though EOL has been reached and declared years ago, MS takes actions for those few running the legacy OS...any technical experience will be appreciated...

Comment: You miss detail, backupexec save to file, library, eedup???

Comment: @DeemV "Dear upper management, our backups are failing for lack of disk space.  To remediate this problem, we require, at a minimum, a new hard drive for our backup target server.  A 2TB nearline SAS hard drive costs approximately $200. Not allocating funds to buy a new hard drive or two will result in not having backups of our data.  Furthermore, our backup server is running on EoL software and we should consider allocating funds to purchase new OS and software licenses for our backup solution to ensure supportability and integrity in our backups. 
 Please advise."

Comment: @HopelessN00b: done that! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Then you've done your job, and, the answer you got back is that the company doesn't care about its backups, so stop working on something the company doesn't care about.  Woohoo, one less thing you have to do... though it might be prudent to start floating that resume.  This doesn't sound like it's going to end well.

Answer (score 1):

Most backup applications cache a part of the backup or create a temporary big log on the server they run backups on. I would recommend to use treesize view or similar application and see which folder and file gets huge. 15GB free for a productive machine is too low too.

Comment: Thank you very much. What stroke me as odd was the fact that previously and with less available space, the job ran smoothly...